# Laravel\Mysql access denied - SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: SHOW TABLES)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**1 - The problem:**
Laravel is denied access to MYSQL.

**2 - Connection test in Laravel:**

```
php artisan tinker
DB::select('SHOW TABLES');
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: SHOW TABLES)'
```

**3 - Checks.** The test machine is not a vps the PHP, MySql, Nginx and Laravel are installed locally on this computer.

a. Script used to create the user in Mysql:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database.* TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

b. Through the terminal, the listing of tables occurs normally:

```
mysql -u user -p
use database;
show tables;
```

c. With a PHP script using PDO access to the DB normally occurs:

```
<?php
  $user = "user";
  $password = "password";
  $database = "database";
  $table = "test";
  try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$database", $user, $password);
    echo "<h2>TODO</h2><ol>";
    foreach($db->query("SELECT value FROM $table") as $row) {
      echo "<li>" . $row['value'] . "</li>";
    }
      echo "</ol>";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
       print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
       die();
 }
```

**4 - Laravel .env:**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=*****
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://www.app.com
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=user
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

**5 - Laravel database.php**

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
'mysql' => [
'driver' => 'mysql',
'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
'prefix' => '',
'prefix_indexes' => true,
'strict' => true,
'engine' => null,
'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
  ]) : [],
],
```

**6 - Server SETUP**

Laravel 8.32.1 | Mysql 8.0.23 | PHP 7.4.3 | Zend Engine 3.4.0 | Nginx 1.18.0 | Ubuntu 20.04.2LTS

Comment: After you did the changes on the .env file, did you clear the cache?  `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Yes, I execute the following sequence of commands after changing the .env php artisan cache:clear | php artisan config:clear | php artisan cache:clear